# Match last path element using JaxRS @Path annotation in Jersey

Tags: java, regex, jersey, jax-rs

Using a previous version of Jersey (~1.12), I used to match the literal path element "data" with one annotation if it occurred at the end of the path, and another annotation if it was somewhere else:

```
@Path("data$")
public Object getDataResource(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    // Matched when 'data' is the last path element
    ...
}

@Path("{name}")
public Object getNamedResource(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    // Matched when 'data' is not the last path element
    ...
}
```

At some point between 1.12 and 1.17, this behavior has changed and the '$' character is now escaped before the pattern is applied to the incoming URI.  Now the first method (getDataResource) is never matched.

For example, when matching `http://.../data/data`, I expect `getNamedResource` to match the first "data" and `getDataResource` to match the second "data".  Instead, `getNamedResource` now matches both.

1. Can I revert to the old behavior where I am responsible for escaping my regex?
2. Is there a new/better/other technique for matching only the last path element on a URI?

Comment: You could try to use `@Encoded` in the "data$" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to manually detect when the second method is matching the last path element and manually delegate to the first.

```
@Path("{name}")
public Object getNamedResource(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    boolean lastElement = uriInfo.getMatchedURIs()
                           .iterator().next().equals(uriInfo.getPath());
    if (lastElement && "data".equals(name)) {
        return getDataResource(uriInfo);
    }
    ...
}
```

Not a bad solution to my particular problem, but I'm still frustrated that Jersey is escaping my pattern without asking me first.